# Pandas: Iterate over rows and find frequency of occurances

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and 3000 rows.

First column is representing time in time-steps. For example first row is 0, second is 1, ..., last one is 2999.

Second column is representing pressure. The pressure changes as we iterate over the rows, but shows a repetitive behaviour. So every few steps we see that it goes to its minimum value (which is 375), then goes up again, then again at 375 etc.

What I want to do in Python, is to iterate over the rows and see:
1) at which time-steps we see pressure is at its minimum

2)Find the frequency between the minimum values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rnd
import scipy.linalg as lin
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import re
from pylab import *
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
row = next(df.iterrows())[0]
dataset = np.loadtxt(df, delimiter=";")

df.columns = ["Timestamp", "Pressure"]
print(df[[0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate row-wise, you can compare the entire column against the `min` value to mask it, you can then use the mask to find the timestep `diff`:

Data setup:

```
In [44]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestep':np.arange(20), 'value':np.random.randint(375, 400, 20)})
df

Out[44]:
    timestep  value
0          0    395
1          1    377
2          2    392
3          3    396
4          4    377
5          5    379
6          6    384
7          7    396
8          8    380
9          9    392
10        10    395
11        11    393
12        12    390
13        13    393
14        14    397
15        15    396
16        16    393
17        17    379
18        18    396
19        19    390
```

mask the df by comparing the column against the `min` value:

```
In [45]:    
df[df['value']==df['value'].min()]

Out[45]:
   timestep  value
1         1    377
4         4    377
```

We can use the mask with `loc` to find the corresponding 'timestep' value and use `diff` to find the interval differences:

```
In [48]:    
df.loc[df['value']==df['value'].min(),'timestep'].diff()

Out[48]:
1    NaN
4    3.0
Name: timestep, dtype: float64
```

You can divide the above by `1/60` to find frequency wrt to 1 minute or whatever frequency unit you desire

Comment: Thanks for your answer EdChum. I was wondering, how can I assign the values of pressure in the `value` field based on the ones I already have? You used `np.random.randit` to make an example, but I don't know how to do it with the already existing ones.

Comment: Sorry my df is just a mock-up as I don't have your data, you can just replace the column names in my code with yours

Comment: I have another question : How can I mask the DF if instead of the minimum values I want to compare the column against a specific value (for example 380)?

Comment: same semantics `df[df['value']==380]` you need to look at [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much for your help!! Btw, since my DF is too long to see all the rows in the console, do you know if there is a way to print the output somewhere else so that I could see all the interval differences?

Comment: You'd need to change the `display.max_rows` option in pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option

Comment: If I don't want to compare it with the min value (or 375), but instead I want to compute the most seen value dynamically and then compare it, how can I do it? I did `count = df['value'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=[False]).nlargest(1)`  which returns value x, and when I try `print(df[df['value'] == count])`, I get this error: **ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare**

Comment: it's because that returns a `Series`, you want just the scalar value: `count = df['value'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=[False]).nl‌​argest(1).values[0]`  here `.values` returns a numpy array and if you subscript into it, it returns the scalar value

Comment: Ok I will post it as another question, since I have issues with this also, thanks though